# Ruby - Group an array of hashes by key

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes (**edited**):

```
data = [
    {id: 1, name: "Amy", win: 1, defeat: 0},
    {id: 1, name: "Amy", win: 1, defeat: 3},
    {id: 2, name: "Carl", win: 0, defeat: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "Carl", win: 2, defeat: 1}
]
```

How can I group or merge into something like this using the key "name" as reference:

```
data = [
    {id: 1, name: "Amy", win: 2, defeat: 3},
    {id: 2, name: "Carl", win: 2, defeat: 2}
]
```

**edited** I forgot to mention that I have an ID too that can't be added.

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191578/how-to-merge-two-array-of-hashes-based-on-hashs-value) help you?

Comment: The rule for merger is not clear. What gives `id: 1` for `name: "Amy"` while giving it `win: 2`?

Comment: @sawa The merger rule is crystal clear: sum wins and defeats grouped by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my try

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

data = [
    {"name"=> "Amy", "win" => 1, "defeat" => 0},
    {"name"=> "Amy", "win" => 1, "defeat" => 3},
    {"name"=> "Carl", "win" => 0, "defeat" => 1},
    {"name"=> "Carl", "win" => 2, "defeat" => 1}
]

merged_hash = data.group_by { |h| h['name'] }.map do |_,val| 
  val.inject do |h1,h2| 
    h1.merge(h2) do |k,o,n|
      k == 'name' ? o : o + n 
    end
  end
end

merged_hash
# => [{"name"=>"Amy", "win"=>2, "defeat"=>3},
#     {"name"=>"Carl", "win"=>2, "defeat"=>2}]
```

Answer to the *edited* post :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

data = [
    {id: 1, name: "Amy", win: 1, defeat: 0},
    {id: 1, name: "Amy", win: 1, defeat: 3},
    {id: 2, name: "Carl", win: 0, defeat: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "Carl", win: 2, defeat: 1}
]

merged_hash = data.group_by { |h| h.values_at(:name, :id) }.map do |_,val| 
  val.inject do |h1,h2| 
    h1.merge(h2) do |k,o,n|
      %i(id name).include?(k) ? o : o + n 
    end
  end
end

merged_hash
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"Amy", :win=>2, :defeat=>3},
#     {:id=>2, :name=>"Carl", :win=>2, :defeat=>2}]
```

Comment: Each of his data lines are JSON.  You can do a  JSON.parse before each line like this `data = [];
data << JSON.parse('    {"name": "Amy",  "win": 1, "defeat": 0} ');
data << JSON.parse('    {"name": "Amy",  "win": 1, "defeat": 3} ');
data << JSON.parse('    {"name": "Carl", "win": 0, "defeat": 1} ');
data << JSON.parse('    {"name": "Carl", "win": 2, "defeat": 1} ');
` .  You can use this before following this answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, your solution is OK, but I forgot to mention that I have an Id too, and I wrote the hash correctly this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one pass with [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and a Hash-memo with an appropriate default. For example:

```
data.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { :id => k.first, :name => k.last, :win => 0, :defeat => 0 } }) do |h, m|
  k = h.values_at(:id, :name)
  m[k][:win   ] += h[:win   ]
  m[k][:defeat] += h[:defeat]
end.values
```

The basic trick is to cache the results indexed by an appropriate key (`[ h[:id], h[:name] ]` in this case) and use the values to store what you're after. The default proc on the `m` Hash autovivifies cached values and then you can apply simple summations during iteration. And a final [`values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values) call to unwrap the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Good place where you can use `group_by`

```
result = []
data.group_by{|d| d[:id]}.each do {|name, records|
  win = 0
  defeat = 0

  records.each do |r|
    win += r[:win]
    defeat += r[:defeat]
  end
  f = records.first
  results << {:id => f[:id], :name => f[:name], :win => win, :defeat => defeat}
end
```